# How to create this painted metal material?

Tags: modeling

[image]I'm beginner at modelling and also in blender. Hope you can help me with this texture.I badly need help. Thanks

Comment: hello, please show the texture you're talking about

Comment: It's like painted metal sir. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest to use the *Principled BSDF* shader, which allows you to create a metallic material with a clear coat. You can add a procedural noise as bump map for the small surface irregularities.

My setup in the screenshot below uses a *Musgrave* texture, which is connected to the *Bump* node which in turn is connected to the *Clearcoat Normal* socket of the *Principled BSDF*. The *Principled BSDF* has the *Base Color* set to nearly black, *Metallic* to 1.0, *Clearcoat* to 1.0 as well.

[image: Render]
[image: Nodes]

Comment: Thank you sir for the suggestion, I will try this as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should try a mix between a *Diffuse* shader (almost black) and a *Glossy* one (very glossy). Your material is a bit grainy, so plug a *Noise Texture* shader into the normals of your shaders.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help sir, I would probably try your suggestion. It helps me a lot.

Comment: It's better to use the principled shader if you're going for realism.  for one thing, it does default fresnel, if you want to learn more about it's benefits, watch blender  gurus youtube tutorial on "the principled shader"

Comment: I would say the 2 are complementary, simple nodes are better at the beginning in my opinion